# htaccess for subdomain to the main domain

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain

we are trying to create .htaccess redirect for our website, here is what we would like to do:

Our domain:
http://freewebsites.com

we would like to redirect all users coming to http://freewebsites.com/username to http://username.freewebsites.com/

This should be for anyone coming to the website. so, we don't need to have a index file or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best method for this would be to use PHP with a GET Variable

Make a page called index.php and place this code in it

```
<?php
// check to see if Variable 'Username' is sent to it
if(isset($_GET["Username"])){
// if sent set User var
$user = $_GET["Username"];
//Send user to domain
header("Location: http://$user.freewebsites.com");

}else{
// if not send back to main domain
header("Location: http://freewebsites.com");
}
?>
```

using this if u send the user to the URL

```
http://freewebsites.com/index.php?Username=TestUser
```

Will be send to

```
http://TestUser.freewebsites.com
```